# How to return 2 different type of data with IGlistkit

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

How do I return two different types of data with IGListkit?

```
func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
      var data = searchCompleter.results
      data += propertyController.properties
      return searchCompleter.results
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Binary operator '+=(*:*:)' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   '[MKLocalSearchCompletion]' and '[Property]'

Comment: When you create `data` it is implicitly typed by the type of `searchCompleter.results`(which is `[MKLocalSearchCompletion]`), so you can't add items of type `Property`  to the `data` array - You need to explicitly declare `data` as an appropriate type (ie. `[ListDiffable]`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
      var data = searchCompleter.results as [ListDiffable]
      let properties = propertyController.properties
      data += properties 
      
      return data
    }
```